# Why is there a difference using std::thread::hardware_concurrency() and boost::thread::hardware_concurrency()?

Tags: linux, multithreading, boost, c++11

The description of the problem itself is pretty simple. I'm testing the differences of std::thread library in C++11 and boost::thread library.

The output of these:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

int main() {
  std::cout << std::thread::hardware_concurrency() << std::endl;
  std::cout << boost::thread::hardware_concurrency() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

gives me different results:

```
0
4
```

Why is that?

PS: The version of the gcc package is 4.6.2-1.fc16 (x86_64). I'm using

```
g++ test.cc -Wall -std=c++0x -lboost_thread-mt -lpthread
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

After reviewing /usr/include/c++/4.6.2/thread

it can be seen that the implementation is actually:

```
// Returns a value that hints at the number of hardware thread contexts.
static unsigned int
hardware_concurrency()
{ return 0; }
```

So problem solved. It's just another feature that hasn't been implemented in gcc 4.6.2

Answer (score 6):

The method employed by your <strike>compiler</strike> installation of boost is supported for your target, whereas your <strike>installation of boost</strike> compiler does not support this feature for your target.

[TFM](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread.hardware_concurrency) says:

> The number of hardware threads available on the current system (e.g. number of CPUs or cores or hyperthreading units), or 0 if this information is not available.

EDIT: scratch that, reverse it.

EDIT2:  This feature is present on [the trunk](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/thread.cc?view=markup#l131), but absent in 4.6.2:

```
~/tmp/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++-v3/src> wc -l thread.cc
104 thread.cc
~/tmp/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++-v3/src> grep concurrency thread.cc | wc -l
0
~/tmp/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++-v3> grep -C 2 VERIFY testsuite/30_threads/thread/members/hardware_concurrency.cc

  // Current implementation punts on this.
  VERIFY( std::thread::hardware_concurrency() == 0 );

  return 0;
```

Comment: But actually boost::thread can display the correct information 4, whereas c++11 gives me 0...

Comment: @derekhh: its very likely that your c++11 implementation is just a skeleton and doesn't actually work

Comment: g++ 4.6.2 targeting `linux-x86_64`, or ...?

Comment: @BrianCain: yeap, it is x86_64.

Comment: More info about its pedigree: http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/thread.cc?view=log

Comment: @derekhh Indeed, C++11 support in gcc 4.6.x is obviously a "work in progress _(at the time the compiler was released)_"; the standard explicitly makes `0` an acceptable fallback value when the real value isn't known, and gcc 4.6.x took advantage of that.  C++11 support in gcc 4.7 is much better, and it does provide an accurate value for `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`.