# Handle std::thread::hardware_concurrency()

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, g++, version

In my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887654/synchronise-push-back-and-stdthread) about `std::thread`, I was advised to use `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`. I read somewhere (which I can not find it and seems like a local repository of code or something), that this feature is not implemented for versions of g++ prior to 4.8.

As a matter of fact, I was the at the same victim position as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8583292/2411320) user. The function will simply return 0. I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7341515/2411320) answer a user implementation. Comments on whether this answer is good or not are welcome!

So I would like to do this in my code:

```
unsinged int cores_n;
#if g++ version < 4.8
 cores_n = my_hardware_concurrency();
#else
 cores_n = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
#endif
```

However, I could find a way to achieve this result. What should I do?

Comment: Reading the [online documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/) might help, especially about [common pre-defined macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros).

Comment: Even when `hardware_concurrency` is implemented, it cannot be relied as a direct mapping to the number of cores. This is what the standard says it returns - *The number of hardware thread contexts*. And goes on to state - *This value should only be considered to be a hint* If your machine has hyperthreading enabled, it's entirely possible the value returned will be 2x the number of cores. If you want a reliable answer, you'll need to use whatever facilities your OS provides.

Comment: I am reading the links, thanks Joachim! @Praetorian the answer I linked did not mention that, good point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is another way than using the *[GCC Common Predefined Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros)*: Check if `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()` returns zero meaning the feature is not (yet) implemented.

```
unsigned int hardware_concurrency()
{
    unsigned int cores = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    return cores ? cores : my_hardware_concurrency();
}
```

You may be inspired by [awgn's source code](https://github.com/awgn/speedcore/blob/master/speedcore.cpp) (GPL v2 licensed) to implement `my_hardware_concurrency()`

```
auto my_hardware_concurrency()
{
    std::ifstream cpuinfo("/proc/cpuinfo");

    return std::count(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(cpuinfo),
                      std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
                      std::string("processor"));
}
```

Comment: Yes, I like that too! However, I haven't checked, but it seems good. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @Daniel. There was an extra parenthesis at the end of the URL. Now the link is correct thanks to you comment. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Based on common predefined macros [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros), kindly provided by Joachim, I did:

```
int p;
#if __GNUC__ >= 5 || __GNUC_MINOR__ >= 8 // 4.8 for example
  const int P = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
  p = (trees_no < P) ? trees_no : P;
  std::cout << P << " concurrent threads are supported.\n";
#else
  const int P = my_hardware_concurrency();
  p = (trees_no < P) ? trees_no : P;
  std::cout << P << " concurrent threads are supported.\n";
#endif
```